# GridSearchCV(OneVsRestClassifier(clf, ...)): 1 optimal set of hyper parameters for all N classifiers vs. 1 optimal set for each classifier

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, grid-search

**Background**

Let's say, we have `L` labels to predict in a multi class (resp. multi label) problem.  Using `OneVsRestClassifier`, there are `L` classifiers being built.  Let's assume, we use `LogisticRegression` for the individual classifiers.

When searching for the optimal hyper parameters using `GridSearchCV` (resp. `RandomizedSearchCV`), we run:

```
GridSearchCV( OneVsRestClassifier( LogisticRegression(), ...) ).fit(X, y)
```

**Question**

By running the `GridSearchCV` command above, we will get 1 set of optimal hyper parameters that will be used to train (resp. refit) all of the `L` classifiers.  So, for example, we will get an optimal value of `C=10`, and that value will be used to refit **all** of the `L` classifiers.

My question is why `GridSearchCV` does not return one distinct set of optimal hyper parameter for each one of the `L` classifiers.  E.g. `label0` would an optimal `C=10`, `label1` would get an optimal `C=0.01`, ... ?
Why was the decision made to return a single set of hyper parameters rather than one set for each one of the classifiers?

**Prior experience**

I am asking because this behaviour is not the same as what I usually get when training each label classifier 'by hand'.  E.g. for some tasks, where I have thousands of labels to predict, I train each label classifier individually (spread over many machines), and consequently I get, most  certainly, different values of hyper parameters for each of the label classifiers.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, but I don't notice the single parameter(s)/score returned by `GridSearchCV().best_params_` or `.best_score_` is corresponded to an optimal choice refitted to all classifiers. Is there any document confirming this?